# At screen Resolution of 1366x768 monitor is flickering

Tags: 14.04, monitor

My monitor starts flickering at higher resolutions but not in lower resolution like 1024x768

Below is the output to: `sudo dmesg | grep -i 'Graphic\|video\|VGA\|error\|fail'`

```
[ 0.127671] DMAR: Disabling IOMMU for graphics on this chipset
[ 0.144016] vgaarb: setting as boot device: PCI:0000:00:02.0
[ 0.144016] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[ 0.144016] vgaarb: loaded
[ 0.144016] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
[ 0.162621] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM
[ 1.760018] pci 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
[ 2.135625] fb0: VESA VGA frame buffer device
[ 2.161753] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.IDE1.GTM_] (Node ffff8800b8665230), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20131115/psparse-536)
[ 2.161759] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.IDE1.CHN1._GTM] (Node ffff8800b86650f0), AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT (20131115/psparse-536)
[ 2.161764] ata4: ACPI get timing mode failed (AE 0x300b)
[ 3.808021] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[ 23.033000] video: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 23.827751] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[ 23.827758] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver
[ 23.872182] vgaarb: device changed decodes: 
PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[ 24.050590] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, Evaluating _DOD (20131115/video-1279)
[ 24.050594] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: no rom: yes post: no)
[ 24.050796] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
[ 37.718437] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[ 47.770428] init: failsafe main process (692) killed by TERM signal
[ 97.681324] [drm:i965_irq_handler] *ERROR* pipe A underrun
```

Additional Details:

Below is the output to `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2e32] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:d613]
Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Monitor Details:

```
Model : Dell E1914H (Bought recently which supports upto 1366x768 resolution and the same was auto detected by xrandr)
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: please add also the output for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: What are the specifications of the monitor?  How old is it?   Please [edit] your question and add this information...